# How to convert JSON Response to String Array

Tags: java, android, json

This is the JSON Response I received from OpenWeatherMap:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 85.84,
    "lat": 20.26
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 721,
      "main": "Haze",
      "description": "haze",
      "icon": "50d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 305.15,
    "pressure": 1007,
    "humidity": 70,
    "temp_min": 305.15,
    "temp_max": 305.15
  },
  "visibility": 5000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.1,
    "deg": 170
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 20
  },
  "dt": 1551686400,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 9113,
    "message": 0.0037,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1551659668,
    "sunset": 1551702153
  },
  "id": 1275817,
  "name": "Bhubaneswar",
  "cod": 200
}
```

While I am able to use Weather by using this code below but unable to convert main to array. Is there anyway I can convert the bolded response to array or String.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);




            for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                String description =jsonPart.getString("description");

                if(main !="" && description !="")
                {
                    message += main + " : " + description + "\r\n";

                }


            }
```

Comment: Changed the tag from [android-studio] to [android] since the question doesn't appear to have anything to do with the IDE specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste your json string to [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website,  and generate your pojo. Use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse your string and bind to generated pojo.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion is, don't parse the JSON by hand. Use third party library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse the JSON. This way you won't run into any typo errors and let the library handle the parsing for you.